# SQL server recursion path id

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

When using recursion with CTE in SQL Server, is there a way to reveal the path id SQL server is using ?

Let's say I have the following table representing edges connected to each other:

```
CREATE TABLE c(id int, n1 int, n2 int);

insert into c( id, n1, n2 ) values ( 100, 1, 2);
insert into c( id, n1, n2 ) values ( 101, 2, 3 );
insert into c( id, n1, n2 ) values ( 102, 3, 4 );
insert into c( id, n1, n2 ) values ( 103, 4, 8 );
insert into c( id, n1, n2 ) values ( 104, 3, 11 );
insert into c( id, n1, n2 ) values ( 105, 11, 12 );
```

I can now use the following recursive query to show what nodes are connected to each other :

```
WITH Nodes
AS
(   
    select c.id, c.n1, c.n2, 1 as level from c where id = 100
    UNION ALL   
    select c.id, c.n1, c.n2, level+1 from c inner join Nodes on Nodes.n2 = c.n1 where c.id != 100
)
SELECT id, n1, n2, level from Nodes where level > 1 order by id;
```

This will give the following result :

```
id  n1  n2  level
101 2   3   2
102 3   4   3
103 4   8   4
104 3   11  3
105 11  12  4
```

There are 2 paths, 101-102-103 & 101-104-105. I want to identify each path, but I think they actually are equal to the recursion paths SQL Server is using, so if I have a way of getting this recursion path id, then I can identify each unique path.

I want my output to look like this :

```
id  n1  n2  level path_id
101 2   3   2     1
102 3   4   3     1
103 4   8   4     1
104 3   11  3     2
105 11  12  4     2
```

As you can see, at node 104 a second path or recursion is encountered. These are the nodes making up the paths :

```
path 1 : 101 - 102 - 103
path 2 : 104 - 105
```

Each path actually starts at node 100, but it is left out of the results by the 'level>1' clause.

Thanks, Steef

Comment: How exactly should the result look alike? Do you want a result with TWO rows and the full path in each?

Comment: Hi Georg, I want an extra column 'path_id' appended

Comment: OK, but then, you would need to output the row with id "101" TWICE, once with path_id "1", and once with path_id "2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like this.

**Data**

```
CREATE TABLE c(id int, n1 int, n2 int);

insert into c( id, n1, n2 ) values ( 100, 1, 2);
insert into c( id, n1, n2 ) values ( 101, 2, 3 );
insert into c( id, n1, n2 ) values ( 102, 3, 4 );
insert into c( id, n1, n2 ) values ( 103, 4, 8 );
insert into c( id, n1, n2 ) values ( 104, 3, 11 );
insert into c( id, n1, n2 ) values ( 105, 11, 12 );
```

**Query**

```
;WITH Nodes
AS
(   
    select c.id, c.n1, c.n2, 1 as level ,convert(varchar(1000),convert(varchar(1000),id) + '/') as pid
    from c where id = 100
    UNION ALL   
    select c.id, c.n1, c.n2, level+1,convert(varchar(1000),nodes.pid + convert(varchar(1000),c.id) + '/') from c inner join Nodes on Nodes.n2 = c.n1 where c.id != 100
)
SELECT id, n1, n2, level,pid from Nodes where level > 1 order by id;
```

The query shows the complete path traversed will the current point by appending the current `id` to the previous nodes in the column `pid`. your output required is not very clear, if you can detail the exact output required in the question, I can update my answer accordingly.

**Edit**
As per your output, you can do something like this.

```
;WITH Nodes
AS
(
    select c.id, c.n1, c.n2, 1 as level ,convert(int,1) as pid
    from c where id = 100
    UNION ALL   
    select c.id, c.n1, c.n2, level+1,convert(int,pid + ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1) pid 
    from c inner join Nodes on Nodes.n2 = c.n1 where c.id != 100
)
SELECT id, n1, n2, level,pid from Nodes where level > 1 order by id;
```

Comment: Hi George, I have added the output I want in my question.

Comment: @Steef - `101` comes in both paths. How do you decide it should come in `path_id 1` and not in `path id 2`

Comment: If a node is in 2 paths, the first one should be used. Path 2 starts at node 104.